# What's the dimension of the affine subspace $S: x-y+1=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that an affine subspace is an hyperplane iff $dim(S)=dim(\mathbb{A})-1$. I know that the affine space in this case is $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{R}^2$, I have to find the dimension of the affine subspace $S: x-y+1=0$. How can I do that? Also, I need to find a reference system for the subspace $S$.

Answer (score 0):

The subspace is given by $S=\{(x,x+1)\mid x\in{\Bbb R}\}$, which is a one-dimensional subspace of ${\Bbb R}^2$ with basis $\{(1,2)\}$.

Comment: Thank you, but how did you find out that S={(x,x+1)}?

Comment: Just have a look at the defining equation: $x+1=y$.

Comment: I'm new to linear algebra, and that's a little bit unclear. My initial intuition was to search for pivots for x-y+1=0, but I guess it doesn't work like that.